# Understanding legacy code: Algorithm to remove radial lens distortion

Tags: computer-vision, c++, camera, distortion, camera-calibration

The method below to remove lens distortion from a camera was written more than ten years ago and I am trying to understand how the approximation works.

```
void Distortion::removeLensDistortion(const V2 &dist, V2 &ideal) const
{
 const int ITERATIONS=10;
 V2 xn;
 xn.x=(dist.x - lensParam.centerX)/lensParam.fX;
 xn.y=(dist.y - lensParam.centerY)/lensParam.fY;

 V2 x=xn;
 for (int i=0;i<ITERATIONS;i++) {
   double r2 = Utilities::square(x.x)+Utilities::square(x.y);
   double r4 = Utilities::square(r2);
   double rad=1+lensParam.kc1 * r2 + lensParam.kc2 * r4;
   x.x/=rad;
   x.y/=rad;
 }
 ideal.x=x.x*lensParam.fX+lensParam.centerX;
 ideal.y=x.y*lensParam.fY+lensParam.centerY;
}
```

As a reminder:

- lensParam.centerX and lensParam.centerY is the principal point
- lensParam.fX and lensParam.fY is the focal length in pixel
- lensParam.kc1 and lensParam.kc2 are the first two radial distortion coefficients. This is $k_1$ and $k_2$ in the formula below.

The formula to **add** lens distortion given the first two radial distortion parameters is as follows:

$$
x_{distorted} = x_{undistorted} \cdot (1+k_1\cdot r^2 + k_2 \cdot r^4) \\
y_{distorted} = y_{undistorted} \cdot (1+k_1\cdot r^2 + k_2 \cdot r^4)
$$
where $r^2=x_{undistorted}^2+y_{undistorted}^2$ and $r^4=(r^2)^2$

In the code above, the term $(1+k_1\cdot r^2 + k_2 \cdot r^4)$ is calculated and saved in the variable `rad` and the distorted x is *divided by* `rad` in each of the ten iterations.

All of the cameras we use have a pincushion distortion (so $k_1<0$)

The question is how is this algorithm approximating the undistorted image points?
Do you know if there is any paper in which this algorithm is proposed?

[The opencv undistortion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958521/understanding-of-opencv-undistortion) may be a bit similar, so that link may be useful but it is not quite the same though.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SP. I happen to have already answered your question in SO: see point 2 of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642083/1435240).